# Using pathlib, parent's parent just returns the first parent itself (parent.parent == parent)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I'm trying to find the parent directory of the directory that my script is located in:

```
this = pathlib.Path(__name__)
parent = this.parent
parent2 = parent.parent
```

But printing them out shows that the second `.parent` isn't working:

```
print(this, this.absolute())
print(parent, parent.absolute())
print(parent2, parent2.absolute())
print(this.parent == this.parent.parent)
```

Yields the output of:

```
__main__ C:\Users\Markus\Projects\PathTest\bin\__main__
. C:\Users\Markus\Projects\PathTest\bin
. C:\Users\Markus\Projects\PathTest\bin
True
```

I'm clueless, what could be the issue?

Comment: using `this = Path(__main__)` everything works as expected... what is `Parent`?

Comment: What is `print(__name__)`? If I run your code on MacOS, both `__name__` *and* this are just `'__main__'`, and it's parent is simply `.'` (and consequently, also the grandparent). There is no expansion to a full path in my case, but that may be different per platform .

Comment: `absolute` will join a relative path with the current working directory.

Comment: @9769953 Yeah, running `print(__name__)` gives me `__main__`, but I don't understand why I can't run `.parent` twice on it, it knows the `absolute()` path well.

Comment: Your last edit shows the problem: pathlib works on the relative directory name, which is not the absolute path name. Hence it gets "stuck" on the single . directory, and the absolute path also remains the same.

Comment: @9769953 I suppose I understand the problem, I'm just surprised that pathlib can't handle `..` for relative paths, even Python's import understands `from ...superparent import stuff`. Anyways, I'm still clueless on how to do this "properly" then

Comment: I suspect that pathlib does as much as possible without performing system calls, for speed and ease. Thus, it works from the string provided, and the directory separator(s) for the system; in that case, it has a relative root which it won't go beyond. This is also the reason why `__name__` instead of `__file__` works. I guess only when methods such as resolve or absolute are called, the underlying system is being polled about its directory structure, or rather, the current location of the file/process its being used in. But this is just a guess; I haven't looked at the actual code.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen I think what you're misunderstanding is that `pathlib` is for manipulating path *syntax*. The path doesn't have to actually exist. It's only when you deliberately resolve it that it will become meaningful in a context. Implicitly it resolves to be relative to the current working directory.

Comment: @PeterWood You're right, that's something I certainly didn't realize when I first asked this question, thanks for the clarification. However, I still think that the parent of `.` should be `..`, and the parent of that should be `../..`, and I'm unable to see why pathlib doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the printout shows: if `parent = '.'` then `parent.parent` will also be `.`.

try to resolve the path beforehand:

```
this = Path(__file__).resolve()
```

also note that `__file__` will give you the path of your file; not `__main__`.

Comment: Alright I suppose I understand the problem now, but `.resolve()` doesn't seem to do anything, all the print outputs stay the same.

Comment: Am I doing this right? `this = pathlib.Path(__name__).resolve(); print(this); print(this.parent.parent == this.parent)` it just outputs: `__main__` and `True`

Comment: `__file__` and not `__main__` is the path of your file. do you have a file or a directory called `__main__`? maybe even try: `Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True)` to  make sure the file exists.

Comment: I do not, I have a single `test.py` file with the above 3 lines and `import pathlib`, and I'm getting the output `__main__` for `print(this)`

Comment: then i suggest you try: `this = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True)`. again: `__file__` and not `__main__` as argument.

Comment: It's just giving me `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '__main__'` with `strict=True`

Comment: exactly! that is why you need to use `__file__`.

Comment: I feel like a moron, all this time you've been saying `__file__` and I've somehow completely missed it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: added that to the answer. no problem!